# iPhone application Icon not registering

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, icons

I am at a complete loss because my application icon simply will not register. I've tried just about everything and the icon still just will not register. I think it may have to do with the fact that I was trying to re-name my project something else, and perhaps the targets now do not match. Can anybody provide advice on why my icon simply will not show up on the phone?

Thanks

Comment: Does ***everything*** include a clean build?

Comment: what does that mean? How do I create a clean build?

Comment: Search for the terms 'clean' and 'clean build folder' under the tab marked 'help' in the OSX menu bar.

Comment: will "cleaning" clear things up?

Comment: In most cases Yes.  On the sim, not so much.  The iOS simulator is a hunk of junk when it comes to UI details, but hey, it's just a simulator.

Comment: do I want to procede with a clean build? It says that it will delete everything in the build file? Also, I'm testing this on my iPhone not sim

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9759/discussion-between-derek-lo-and-codafi)

Comment: Yes, you do want to.  The build folder is just the place where your old binary resides on your system, it won't delete your project or any of it's files (that would sure be one stupid command!)

Comment: Haha quite true. Now I think I've narrowed down my issue. I don't think it actually has anything to do with the app icon, but rather all images in general. Have you run into a problem where your images show up on the iPhone simulator but do not on an actual device. Xcode keeps throwing errors for my images by saying that "the compiler claims to succeed"...

Comment: Go into build settings and set `PNG compression` to NO.

Comment: oh my god. you are the absolute man.

Comment: can I just say that I seriously thank you. I mean I've been racking my brain for a good 2 hours now and I finally got this to work. Thank you so much, seriously. Can I ask you why this works and what PNG Compression does?

Comment: For future reference, to do a clean build: Cmd + Shift + K (clean), then build and run again.

Comment: @derek.lo I've posted my comment as an answer and expounded a little to answer your last question.  Remember to upvote and mark as accepted if it helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PNG compression is a little algorithm that the compiler performs to cut down on the space images take up in your app.  Unfortunately, it has been the Bain of many a programmer's existence because it often doesn't de-compress the images once the binary is made and ran.  Just set it to NO.

PNG compression also optimizes the PNG's for an iOS device like so:

> 1. Extra critical chunk (CgBI).
> 2. Byteswapped (RGBA –> BGRA) pixel data, presumably for high-speed >direct blitting to the framebuffer.
> 3. Zlib header, footer, and CRC removed from the IDAT chunk.
> 4. Premultiplied alpha (color′ = color * alpha / 255).